# Is there a way to add a label in between two other labels?

Tags: python, tkinter

On another project, I have a bunch of labels that gets updated whenever a list of strings is given. But if I wanted to add a string to this list and show that with the labels, I would have to destroy and remake all of them again. To simplify it, the below code is my starting point.

```py
from tkinter import *
  
root = Tk()
a = Label(root, text ="Hello World")
a.pack()

b = Label(root, text = "Goodbye World")
b.pack()

# third label to add between label A and B
  
root.mainloop()
```

Is there some kind of insert function or other way to solve this?

EDIT: answer from Bryan Oakley:

Should use the before/after parameter in pack of label

```py
# third label to add between label A and B
c = Label(root, text="Live long and prosper")
c.pack(before=b)
```

Comment: You can use the `.tkraise()` and `.lower()` methods to reorder the widgets within their parent container - for example, after creating the third Label, do `b.tkraise()` to have the new one be in the middle.

Comment: @jasonharper: no, that's not what `.tkraise()` and `.lower()` do. Those methods change the stacking order in the Z axis, not the packing order in the Y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which you call `pack` matters, in that it establishes the order in which the widgets appear relative to each other. `pack` also provides arguments to change that order. You can specify `before` to add a widget before another widget, and `after` to place the widget after.

This code places the third label before widget `b`:

```
# third label to add between label A and B
c = Label(root, text="Live long and prosper")
c.pack(before=b)
```

This code places the third label after widget `a`:

```
# third label to add between label A and B
c = Label(root, text="Live long and prosper")
c.pack(after=a)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I knew there had to be a way to do this. Bad on me for looking at the parent widgets for an insert function or something. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that this is what you meant with your question but if you want to insert a third label between Label1 and Label2 (a, b) just insert it manualy.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
a = Label(root, text="Hello World")
a.pack()

# third label to add between label A and B
c = Label(root, text="Middle Label")
c.pack()

b = Label(root, text="Goodbye World")
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

this way it's gonna show on the screen between a and b.
and if you want to insert new text to an already existing Label you can just use the .configure() method to change the text of a specific Label whenever you want, like this:

```
from tkinter import *

lst = ["Oof"]

root = Tk()
a = Label(root, text="Hello World")
a.pack()

# third label to add between label A and B
c = Label(root, text="Middle Label")
c.pack()

b = Label(root, text="Goodbye World")
b.pack()

# Here I will add a simple code that asks the user to enter a number 
# between one and ten, if it's between those numbers then change the
# text to "Nice Choice!" else to first element of the list called lst
guess = int(input("Enter a number (1 - 10): "))

if 1 <= guess <= 10:
    c.configure(text="Nice choice!")
else:
    c.configure(text=f"{lst[0]}")  # Using f string

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to go with manually adding because label A and B would be added when the program is run, while label C would be added on user input. But thank you still